# How Can I Extract title Attribute from image in other div

Tags: jquery, image, attributes, title, alt

***HTML:***

```
<img class="thumb_img" title="Sample title here" src="http://example.com/test.jpg" />
```

I want to extract `title` attribute from `img` and add it as text in `div`.

---

*Result:*

```
<img class="thumb_img" title="Sample title here" src="http://example.com/test.jpg" />

<div class="title_container">Sample title here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `attr()` function to get the value of any attribute.

```
var title = $("imgSelector").attr('title');
```

Then to insert it you could use `text()` if you are expecting only raw text. Or `html()` if the contents could be markup.

```
$("divSelector").text(title);
```

`imgSelector` and `divSelector` are the selectors for the image and for the target div. I'm not sure if you have given pseudo code or your production code so you'll have to substitute it for what you are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the title attribute from the image

```
title = $("img.thumb_img").attr('title');
```

Place it in the div (and use a more specific selector :P)

```
$('div').html(title);
```